# check in page customization in UCM -adding check boxes for metadata

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-ucm

I want to allow the user to select multiple options for one metadata,and we need to provide check boxes for the same.I have modified the respective include and added the java script ,but some how the value is not getting assigned to the metadata:
I have modified the include and added JS as follows ,but the metadata is not getting assigned the selected values,can any one tell me where am I going wrong:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
           function getSelected(Language) {
                                       var selected = new Array();
                                       var index = 0; for (var intLoop=0; intLoop < Language.length; intLoop++) {
                                       if (Language[intLoop].selected) {             index = selected.length;        
                                                                       selected[index] = new Object;    
                                                                       selected[index].value = Language[intLoop].value;          
                                                                        selected[index].index = intLoop;         }      }      
                                                                            return selected;
                                                                           }
function submit(selected)
{
var value =selected;
xTranslateTo = value;
}
</script>
<$if strEquals(fieldName, "xTranslateTo") and not (isInfo or isQuery)$>
<tr <$strTrimWs(inc("std_nameentry_row_attributes"))$>>
<td <$if captionFieldWidth$>width="<$captionFieldWidth$>"<$endif$> <$if isInfo$>align=right<$endif$>><$strTrimWs(inc(fieldCaptionInclude))$></td>
<td <$if isFieldInfoOnly$>colspan="100"<$endif$> <$if captionEntryWidth$>;width="<$captionEntryWidth$>"<$endif$>><$inc(fieldEntryInclude)$>

<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX  NAME="Language" VALUE="English">English
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX  NAME="Language" VALUE="Italian">Italian
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX  NAME="Language" VALUE="French">French
<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX  NAME="Language" VALUE="German" >German</td>
</tr>
 <a href="javascript:;" onclick=" getSelected()">
<$else$>
<$include super.std_nameentry_row$>
<$endif$>
```

Can any one throw some light on where am I going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to display check boxes and assign comma separated value to the metadata,now all i'm left to do is to display the checked boxes when the user calls for update metadata form.

```
<$if strEquals(fieldName, "xLang") and not (isInfo or isQuery)$>
<script>
function boxFunc()
{
    var textval=document.getElementsByName('xLang')[0];
        var langs=document.getElementsByName("ucmlang");
        larray="";
            for(i=0;i<langs.length;i++)
          {
             if(langs[i].checked)
                   {
                     larray=larray+langs[i].id+",";
                   }
      }
           larray=larray.substring(0,larray.length-1);
          textval.value=larray;

}
</script>
<tr <$strTrimWs(inc("std_nameentry_row_attributes"))$>>
<td<$if captionFieldWidth$>width="<$captionFieldWidth$>"<$endif$> <$if isInfo$>align=right<$endif$>><$strTrimWs(inc(fieldCaptionInclude))$></td>
<td <$if isFieldInfoOnly$>colspan="100"<$endif$> <$if captionEntryWidth$>;width="<$captionEntryWidth$>"<$endif$>><$inc(fieldEntryInclude)$></td>
<td><!– addition –>English<!– end addition –><input type="checkbox"  name="ucmlang"  id = "English" onclick="boxFunc()">
<td><!– addition –>French<!– end addition –><input type="checkbox"  name="ucmlang"  id = "French" onclick="boxFunc()"></td>
<td><!– addition –>Italian<!– end addition –><input type="checkbox"  name="ucmlang"  id = "Italian" onclick="boxFunc()"></td>
<td><!– addition –>German<!– end addition –><input type="checkbox"  name="ucmlang"  id = "German" onclick="boxFunc()"></td>
<td><!– addition –>Japanese<!– end addition –><input type="checkbox"  name="ucmlang"  id = "Japanese" onclick="boxFunc()"></td>
</tr>
<$else$>
<$include super.std_nameentry_row$>
<$endif$>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is this line:

```
xTranslateTo = value;
```

IDOC is running on server side, hence all metadata variables are not accessible in JS on  client side. Right now your script is just setting value of the local JS variable with name 'xTranslateTo', nothing else.

You need to create hidden field 'xTranslateTo' and populate it in your JS instead of this local variable. Once this hidden field is sent during submit it will be parsed on the server side and put to the corresponding metafield.

Of course it will also require an additional parsing on IDOC for setting previously selected languages' checkboxes.

Comment: Can you please tell me how do i assign the selected values to the hidden field 'xTranslateTo'.

Comment: There are many ways to implement functionality like yours.
If you are using 11g you may use standard functionality for multiple selections - just define your field as having an Option List (in Configuration Manager). It can be based on view (db table) or predefined list.
If you can't use the standard approach (lets say because of your application design you need to have exactly checkboxes, not lists) - you may, again, define this field as an option list based on view and write your own component/include/idoc to parse schema values by yourself and display it as checkboxes.

Comment: Here an example of code which gets all languages from the view called TranslationLanguagesView (Language and Code are fields of this vew):
<!--$getViewValuesResultSet("TranslationLanguagesView", "", "")-->
<!--$loop SchemaData-->
 <!--$Language--> - <!--$Code--><br/>
<!--$endloop-->

Comment: Also you'll need to update TranslationLanguages hidden field every time user (un)ticks one of these checkboxes, for example, by putting all language codes as comma-separated string in it (JS). Vice versa if user is opening previously saved document you need to prepare list of checkboxes, split the TranslationLanguages and enable corresponding checkboxes.

Comment: If you have more than one place where such field type is required it has sense to override standard UCM include std_display_field to provide such kind of lists (multiple checkboxes) all over your application.

Comment: i have a question here,do i need to modify the std_display_field include to show the checked checkboxes on update metadata service call or we can edit the same (std_nameentry_row) include to show the checked checkboxes on the update page?